# redirect facebook app to canvas url if host url is hit directly

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have iframe based facebook app, I just want to do is that whenever someone hits the application url directly http://mysite.com must be redirect to my facebook canvas url for this app say http://apps.facebook.com/mysite. This seems pretty easy but unfortunately its not clicking in my mind

any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

the application is in codeigniter

**EDIT**

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

php_value error_reporting 7
php_flag display_errors On
php_value auto_prepend_file prepend.php
```

say my domain is

```
http://abc.com/mysitefolder
```

my facebook app link is

```
http://apps.facebook.com/myappname
```

please consider http and https conversion too

also guyz one suggestion too as you see am using prepend in htaccess its just to get the user timezone for some date time stuff, is this fine am using it this way? the file actually sets a cookie for a user on very first visit to the site per session

Best Regards
Junaid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any canvas page for an app that comes from Facebook will have `$_REQUEST['signed_request']` defined. You could check for the existence of this request variable and if it is not set, redirect to Facebook.

Comment: well Jason, I was looking for this solution but I would have to validate the request that is not true on every page of my app because I am not including facebook stuff on every page so not including facebook class hence only relying on signed_request parameter wont be safe I guess right? plz correct me if am wrong thanks.

Comment: Well, it depends what you are after. If you want to absolutely prevent anyone from getting to your app outside of Facebook then you'd probably want to validate the request to make sure it's legitimate. If you just want the normal user experience to redirect if they accidentally navigate to your app, then a simple `isset()` will do.

Answer (score 0):

well as far as i know there isn't any server side coding to do so... then again how could there be since it's all happening on the frontside of things what you could do is using javascript like so

```
if(window!=window.top){i am iframed now redirect or w/e you wanna do}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to redirect the domain name to the app, not the other way around, the fact that the app is in an iFrame isn't relevant.

The best way to do it is using .htaccess, in my opinion. This means that you can use custom URLs such as mydomainname.com/mypagename/, which would redirect to apps.facebook.com/myappname/mypagename/, so you can advertise your app easier. Another benefit is that you don't have to rely on Javascript. Some people (very small amount) have it turned off, but why parse all the PHP code to do it?

So, what you can do is have the root domain "blank" and only include the following in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomainname.com/ [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.mydomainname.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

QSA will also attach query parameters to the destination URL, such as "?ref=email".

Of course, if you keep the app code on the same domain, in the root, you don't really need to do anything, just tweak your authentification code.

If this doesn't work for you, please give us more details:

- Where does the app "live"
- If the app sits in the mydomainname.com, what happens when you access the URL directly?
- How do you do the authentification?

Code helps, obviously.

Unless mydomainname.com isn't specific for the app, I'd recommend hosting the actual app on a subdomain. Actually, regardless, should help you organize. Or you might want to make the app accesibile as a website as well, with a Facebook login option.

Cheers

Comment: Hey Claudiu, I liked the way you said but unfortunately m not good at htaccess stuff, I would appreciate if you can give em htaccess in accordance with codeigniter { if it need something special } see my edit am giving my current htaccess plz write in the actual stuff i would need Regards

Comment: Are you hosting the app on http://abc.com/mysitefolder? 

Also, I'm happy to help out, but preferably you'd learn, you wouldn't just copy paste snippets of code without understanding what they actually do as that won't help you with anything.

Comment: I wont do anything without knowing what its doing actually.

Yes my site is at `abc.com/mysitefolder` and the facebook application url is `apps.facebook.com/myappname` and what i want is any call to `http|https://abc.com/mysitefolder*` goes to `http|https://apps.facebook.com/myappname*` {* would be any controller or arguments as its a CodeIgniter application}
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `mysitefolder` is a folder at my test server where my site reside, it may be removed when I move the site to live server {Infomation}

Comment: Dude, is the app pulling the content from abc.com/mysitefolder and you only want to redirect abc.com to http|https://apps.facebook.com/myappname? 

If yes, is CodeIgniter installed in the root of abc.com? Sorry, but it's hard to figure out how your system is setup. Where do you plan to move when you go live?

Comment: sorry for being confusing, English is not my native language :)

`abc.com` is my test server

`http://abc.com/MY_PROJECT_FOLDER` {this contains my codeigniter files}

my facebook app is `http://apps.facebook.com/MY_APP_NAME` loads everything from my server in its iframe this is how facebook works 

The problem is that user can access my web application by going to `http://abc.com/MY_PROJECT_FOLDER` [web interface] and `http://apps.facebook.com/My_APP` [FB interface] 

I want anyone comes to `http://abc.com/MY_PROJECT_FOLDER` redirects to `http://apps.facebook.com/My_APP`

hope its now clear :)